# Show the series $e^{-\cos n}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to show whether or not $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty{e^{-\cos(n)}}$ converges or diverges. I know that it diverges.

So I did this by using comparison test and got $e^{-\cos(n)} > \ln(e^{-\cos(n)})=-\cos(n)$ and since $-\cos(n)$ diverges, so must $e^{-\cos(n)}$.

Is this a valid way to show this series diverges?

Comment: What is $\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{-\cos(n)}$?

Comment: You can only do comparison if you know the terms are all positive.  $-\cos(n)$ is not always positive...

Comment: @TravisJ The limit wouldn't exist correct? Because its a trig function. So then the limit doesn't equal 0 and thus must diverge?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following theorem:

> If $\sum a_n$ converges then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

and using this you need only to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\cos(n)}\not =0$

Comment: Oh wow, I totally knew that and overthought this! Thank you!

Comment: However since the limit wouldn't exist here, does this work, since that means it still doesn't equal 0?

Comment: @mconn yes it works because if either the limit does not exist or it's not equal to $0$ then the series diverges

Comment: sweet! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

And to show that
the sum diverges to $\infty$,
since $\cos n \ge -1$,
$e^{\cos n} \ge \frac1{e}$.